# How to access keycloak admin page with ingress path url

Tags: docker, kubernetes, keycloak, kubernetes-ingress

I have deployed keycloak on kubernetes cluster and I want to access it with ingress path url, but I am getting 503 service unavilable when trying to access. But with cluster-ip I am able to access keycloak. With /auth I am able to access the main page of keycloak, i.e https://my-server.com/keycloak-development/auth/, but when I try to access admin console it goes to 503 error.

deployment.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "apps/v1"
  kind: "Deployment"
  metadata: 
    name: "keycloak-development"
    namespace: "development"
  spec: 
    selector: 
      matchLabels: 
        app: "keycloak-development"
    replicas: 1
    strategy: 
      type: "RollingUpdate"
      rollingUpdate: 
        maxSurge: 1
        maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 5
    template: 
      metadata: 
        labels: 
          app: "keycloak-development"
      spec: 
        containers: 
          - 
            name: "keycloak-development"
            image: "mykeycloak-image:latest"
            imagePullPolicy: "Always"
            env: 
              - 
                name: "NODE_ENV"
                value: "development"
              -
                name: "PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING"
                value: "true"
              
              -
                name: "KEYCLOAK_URL"
                value: "https://my-server.com/keycloak-development/"

                

                
            ports: 
              - 
                containerPort: 53582
        imagePullSecrets: 
          - 
            name: "keycloak"
```

service.yaml

```
--
  apiVersion: "v1"
  kind: "Service"
  metadata: 
    name: "keycloak-development"
    namespace: "development"
    labels: 
      app: "keycloak-development"
  spec: 
    ports: 
      - 
        port: 53582
        targetPort: 8080
    selector: 
      app: "keycloak-development"
```

ingress.yaml

```
---
  apiVersion: "networking.k8s.io/v1beta1"
  kind: "Ingress"
  metadata: 
    name: "keycloak-development-ingress"
    namespace: "development"
    annotations: 
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/$1"
  spec: 
    rules: 
      - 
        host: "my-server.com"
        http: 
          paths: 
            - 
              backend: 
                serviceName: "keycloak-development"
                servicePort: 53582
              path: "/keycloak-development/(.*)"
```

dockerfile

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-minimal

ENV KEYCLOAK_VERSION 12.0.1
ENV JDBC_POSTGRES_VERSION 42.2.5
ENV JDBC_MYSQL_VERSION 8.0.22
ENV JDBC_MARIADB_VERSION 2.5.4
ENV JDBC_MSSQL_VERSION 8.2.2.jre11

ENV LAUNCH_JBOSS_IN_BACKGROUND 1
ENV PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING false
ENV JBOSS_HOME /opt/jboss/keycloak
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8

ARG GIT_REPO
ARG GIT_BRANCH
ARG KEYCLOAK_DIST=https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/releases/download/$KEYCLOAK_VERSION/keycloak-$KEYCLOAK_VERSION.tar.gz

USER root

RUN microdnf update -y && microdnf install -y glibc-langpack-en gzip hostname java-11-openjdk-headless openssl tar which && microdnf clean all 

ADD tools /opt/jboss/tools
ENV KEYCLOAK_USER admin
ENV KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD admin 

RUN /opt/jboss/tools/build-keycloak.sh

USER 1000

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8443

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/jboss/tools/docker-entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD ["-b", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Note:- I am able to access keycloak and admin page with cluster-ip

Comment: How exactly are you accessing it with cluster IP ? What path do you specify ?

Comment: @mario, I am just using the cluster-ip of the pod followed by the port number

Comment: @SVD did you find any solution for this? Can you please share.

Comment: @xbmono, you need to add this two env variables in your deployment.yaml file to work, KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL, KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After finding a lot I found the solution, we need to add these env variables to our deployment.yaml file to work

1. KEYCLOAK_USER
2. KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
3. PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING (value:"true")
4. KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL (In my case it was something like this:- https://my-server.com/keycloak-development/auth/ )
5. KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_URL (In my case value for it was something like this:- https://my-server.com/keycloak-development/auth/realms/master/admin/)

For Docker image you can use (quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:8.0.2)

While accessing the key-cloak application if you are using ingress based routing you need to add /auth/ to your ingress path url to access (Somthing like this:- https://my-server.com/keycloak-development/auth/ )